# My react native tensorflow model (which I converted from keras using tfjs converter) gives the same prediction for every image

Tags: reactjs, react-native, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow.js

So I trained a keras model on 3 classes for Image recognition. Then I converted this model to use it in TensorflowJs which yield me a model.json and a weight file. I loaded this model into the react native application by following this blog post -> https://blog.tensorflow.org/2020/02/tensorflowjs-for-react-native-is-here.html

However, no matter which Image I pass to this model now, it is giving the same result.
I am first converting the image into a tensor using the following preprocess function.

```
  // Function converts image to tensor
  const imageToTensorf = (rawImageData) => {
    console.log("Converting Image to tensor");
    const TO_UINT8ARRAY = true;
    const { width, height, data } = jpeg.decode(rawImageData, TO_UINT8ARRAY);
    console.log(`width of the image -> ${width} and ${height}`);

    const buffer = new Uint8Array(width * height * 3);
    let offset = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < buffer.length; i += 3) {
      buffer[i] = data[offset];
      buffer[i + 1] = data[offset + 1];
      buffer[i + 2] = data[offset + 2];

      offset += 4;
    }

    const normed = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) normed[i] = buffer[i] / 244.0; // Normalize

    return tf.tensor3d(normed, [height, width, 3]).expandDims();
  };
```

Following is the function which gets called after I press the button to predict the specific Image. Please note that the image resides in my assets folder and I am not camera to snap it, this is simply for testing purpose.

```
  //Main Function
  async function predictPose() {
    console.log("Processing Images");
    const image = require("./assets/img/t4.jpg");
    const imageAssetPath = Image.resolveAssetSource(image);
    const response = await fetch(imageAssetPath.uri, {}, { isBinary: true });
    const rawImageData = await response.arrayBuffer();
    const imageTensor = imageToTensorf(rawImageData);

    console.log(`Shape of image tensor -> ${imageTensor.shape}`);

    const model = await tf
      .loadLayersModel(bundleResourceIO(modelPath, modelWeights))
      .then((m) => {
        console.log("Model Loaded Sucessfully !! ");

        console.log("here shape of image tensor is ", imageTensor.shape);

        const pred = m.predict(imageTensor);

        console.log("prediction complete");
        console.log(pred);

        console.log("//////////////////");

        console.log(pred.dataSync());
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(`Error !! ${err}`));

    // 0 0 1

    return model;
  }
```

No matter which Image I pass, it always give the same result. I have made sure, I am resizing the image to 224X224 before passing it and normalizing it.
Following is my log:

```
Tensorflow is ready . . .
Processing Images
Converting Image to tensor
width of the image -> 224 and 224
Shape of image tensor -> 1,224,224,3
Model Loaded Sucessfully !! 
here shape of image tensor is  Array [
  1,
  224,
  224,
  3,
]
prediction complete
Tensor {
  "dataId": Object {},
  "dtype": "float32",
  "id": 1865,
  "isDisposedInternal": false,
  "kept": false,
  "rankType": "2",
  "scopeId": 969,
  "shape": Array [
    1,
    3,
  ],
  "size": 3,
  "strides": Array [
    3,
  ],
}
////////////////// Result : - //
Float32Array [
  0,
  0,
  1,
]
```

I have tested the same Images on my orignal keras model and they give accurate predictions.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I noticed you're normalizing by dividing by 244.  Why 244?  I've usually seen either 128 or 256.   If you're not normalizing the same, that's the issue.  Can you verify the image tensor values look similar to the react native values for the same image?   Meaning same normalization, batching, etc.   If you're off even by a little, you won't get errors, you'll just get useless results.